# Primer Badge Awarded with Self-Filled Request

Tags: discussion, badges, documentation

I can self-earn the [Primer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5855/primer) by requesting a topic and then filling the request by creating the topic myself. Is this intentional?

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/16777). I both proposed and created the topic and first example for NSScanner on the Swift Documentation page.

Comment: This is potentially intentional, see [Did I just award myself the Backer badge?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334576/2415822)