# Did I just award myself the Backer badge?

Tags: discussion, documentation, badges

I have just received the backer badge:

[image: Backer badge]

As you can also see, I have received +2 rep for an edit of the [C# arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1429/arrays#t=201609142323084519533) documentation.

That example again, was only upvoted once and that's done by myself:

[image: Upvotes on example]

To me this looks like I've awarded the backer badge to myself, which is not the typical way of getting badges.

Since there's no way for me to check the source of the badge, this is just a guess. But since I don't contribute much and these events happened in a very short period of time, it's very likely that it happened that way.

Does that match the defined requirements of this badge or is it a bug?

Comment: *"Since there's no way for me to check the source of the badge"* there is....kinda. you can see when you were awarded the badge and match this to something in your profile which matches what the bade is awarded for, ie. your +2 you got 7 minutes prior. not exactly perfect

Comment: Aren't almost all of the badges self-awarded? Vote X times, ask X good questions, ...?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The badge is given to you when you upvote any example—including one that you contributed to. It seems you upvoted [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1429/arrays/13218/copying-arrays#t=201609150034171242768) to which you are a [major contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/13218). (Note: you can't give yourself *reputation* for voting on an example you contributed to.)

Did you award the badge to yourself? Yes! And so did everyone else who earned the badge. As [Jeff explained](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/):

> Bronze badges are awarded for basic use of the Stack Overflow site; they encourage people to use all the typical, routine functions of the site: posting questions, answering questions, voting up or down, tagging posts, editing, filling out your user profile, and so forth. Bronze badges are relatively easy to get and provide immediate positive feedback to new users.

So most bronze badges are just there to help you learn the basic functions of the site. Upvoting Examples is about as basic a function as there is for Documentation. So great work, but [don't get cocky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOt4H.gif).

And to be clear, you got a +2 because [three reviewers approved](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95718) your edit. That's entirely separate from the Backer badge.

Comment: Hey Jon, I've also observed this behavior on the Primer badge, is that intentional as well?  Meta: [Primer Badge Awarded with Self-Filled Request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328668/2415822)

Comment: @JAL: Correct. Or rather, the important thing is that you create a Topic Request that's actionable. Getting an upvote from someone else or having the topic created (which requires a human review) proves you aren't just writing junk in that space.